# Using namespaces in Prestashop module

Tags: php, namespaces, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

How we can make the Prestashop module compatible with version 1.6 that uses namespaces, As I'm looking into the Prestashop documentation which says `PrestaShop 1.6 does not fully support namespaces. They throw some issues when used in specific places.` Is there any alternative way to this?
Ref: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/core-updates/1.6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use namespace or "use" word for the main file.

I think you can use just full name in you code for example:

```
$data = \PrestaShop\Some\ClassName::getData();
```

or if you want to use namespace as you want.
you can make an empty class for the main file and make a class with your namespace for the parent.

so we have modules/yourmodule/yourmodule.php as the main file

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/classes/yourmoduleparent.php');

class YourModule extends \YourModule\Bootstrap {
    
    // The module codes have been transferred
    // to the "/classes/yourmoduleparent.php" file.  
    
}
```

in modules/yourmodule/classes/yourmoduleparent.php

```
<?php

namespace YourModule;

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

use Module;
use Configuration;
use Context;
use Tools;
use Controller;
use PrestaShopException;
use Hook;

class Bootstrap extends Module {
    
    // Your module codes
    
}
```